# print all options of 1s and 0s in a binary sequence with missing places

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following sequence with missing 1s and 0s:

```
"01010xx101xxx001"
```

And I need to print all possible sequences instead of the missing places marked by `"x"`

How can I do it if I might also need to change the number of `"x"`s?

Comment: You could start by asking yourself, how many lines or combinations will you need to produce? This is given 5 x's, each being 0 or 1.

Comment: Of course, in my example it's 2^5, so I need to first pass on the string to get number of `x`'s, and then a loop with `2^x`, but I couldn't get it to work after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following, using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

def combs(string):
    for p in map(iter, product("01", repeat=string.count("x"))):
        yield "".join(c if c in "01" else next(p) for c in string)

        # maybe more consistent:
        # yield "".join(next(p) if c == "x" else c for c in string)

        # or shortest, with some operator trickery
        # yield "".join(c!="x" and c or next(p) for c in string)

for c in combs("01010xx101xxx001"):
    print(c)

0101000101000001
0101000101001001
0101000101010001
0101000101011001
0101000101100001
0101000101101001
# ...
```

Some documentation on the utils used here:

- [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)
- [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
- [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators)

Comment: I second that - beautiful. I am new to Python, never saw `itertools` before. It works, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the compliments :) knowing the toolbox allows you some poetic density in Python.

Comment: I was trying to solve this as well, but I was struggling with filling `x`s using a tuple output from `product`. Converting the tuple into an iterator is so clever. I am awestruck.

Comment: +1 What is extremely good about this solution, is that you can rather easily change it to e.g. replace 'x' with all combinations of 'abc' (or other similar cases).

Answer (score 1):

There's already a pretty good answer, and I suggest you study it.
Here's another solution that I think walks you a bit more through each step:

```
l = '1010xx101xxx001'

# count x's
count = len([c for c in l if c == 'x'])

# There will be 2 ^ {count} combinations, so iterate from 0 to 2 ^ {count} - 1
for i in range(2 ** count):
    # Get the binary representation of i
    b = str(bin(i)).replace('0b', '')

    # Pad with zero's so we get {count} digits ('1' becomes '00001')
    b_p = '0' * (count - len(b)) + b

    # Replace x's one at a time
    out = l
    for digit in b_p:
        out = out.replace('x', digit, 1)
    print(out)
```